# "Stuck" in drag mode

Tags: release-freya, mouse

My cursor frequently gets "stuck" in drag mode. For example, I'll start dragging a window header or border, but when I release the mouse button, the cursor will keep dragging. It's as if Elementary doesn't realize I've released the button. Opening Slingshot usually gets the cursor to go back into normal mode.

Similarly, when I click and hold an app header to drag it, the app will maximize instead. This keeps happening until I log out and back in again.

[Edit] I'm also experiencing the two-finger scroll issue noted in [this Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1454473). Not sure whether it's related.

This behavior doesn't happen in Windows or Fedora 22.

Any thoughts on how I might fix this? Is this a driver issue, a problem with Pantheon, or something else? I'm running Freya 0.3.2 on a Dell XPS 13 and using the built-in trackpad. Thanks in advance for your help!